# 表形式用のmarkdown記法はないのでしょうか？

Tags: サポート, 機能の要求, markdown

[エミュレータがフリーズするようになった](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16669/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%8C%E3%83%95%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F)
という自分の質問でスペックを記載する際、表形式にしたいと思い
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-helpを読みました。
ですが、表形式用のmarkdown記法を見つけることはできませんでした。

ネットで調べてみるとmeta.stackexchange.comに同じような質問がありましたが、
[Is there Markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables)
さっと見た感じこれという記法はなさそうでした。
(英語苦手なので文章については全く読んでおらず、私が誤解している可能性もあります。)

試しに直接tableタグ等を書いてみましたが、使えなさそうなのでやめました。
StackoverflowにはGitHub・Qiita・redmineなどのような表形式用のmarkdown記法等はないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

挙げておられる質問の [Pëkka](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138112/)氏による[回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/73567) より:

```
-----------------------------------
| いいえ  |  残念ながら |  ありません |
-----------------------------------
|    一応こういうのはできますが..     |
-----------------------------------
| ぜひとも             |  あるべき   |
-----------------------------------
```

(僕の環境ではこれで揃うのですが、和文フォントの幅等によってずれるかも知れません)

[なぜ？という別の質問](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243188)についた[回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243189)`(*)`は、上で挙げておられる質問についた[この回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228464)を参照し、最終的に行き着くのは、Database Administrators meta で表形式をサポートする拡張の[導入が提案された](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/934)`(**)`ことに対する、モデレータの[Anna Lear](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5879)氏による[回答](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966)です。以下、マークダウン拡張に関係のある前半部をざっくり訳します（間違いがあればわかる方編集してください）。

> 今のところ、表形式をサポートする拡張シンタックスを導入する予定はありません。拡張の導入自体は困難ではないのですが、投稿中の表の表示を正しくやるのはかなり難しいだろうからです。
>
> 既存の拡張はいくつかありますが(PHP Markdown とか)、構文があまり直観的ではないし、table やネストした table などでページのレイアウトが崩れるということにすぐになってしまうのです。

`(*)` （[Matthew Haugen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/263510) 氏による）も訳してみます。

> そこでわかりやすく言い換えているのをもう一回わかりやすく言い換えると、導入するとレイアウトに関してページのあれやこれやがぐちゃぐちゃになる、ということです。例えば許容できる幅より広い表を想像してみましょう（というのも、表は幅を強制的に指定するのが比較的にやりやすいから）。全部 `iframe` に入れるのがその点では一番いい代替策でしょうが、それはそれでいいUIとは言いがたいでしょう。

（なお、これに対しては「スクロールしたらいいのでは？」というコメントがついています。）

---

というわけで、まとめると「表を導入した時に、どんな状況でもレイアウトが崩れないようにやるのがかなりしんどい。 code block の中でも表を作れはするから導入が必須というわけでもない」というので導入されていないようです。

ただ、和文欧文を混ぜた表について幅を綺麗に揃えるのは若干手間がかかります（上の表も、terminal で幅を揃えたあと実際ここに貼り付けて修正する必要がありました）。 `(**)` の議論の根拠としても挙がっている通り、Mathjax が(Markdown 拡張によってではなく、スクリプトを走らせることで)導入されているサイトがあるなど、サイトごとの自由度は多少あるようですから、日本語版スタックオーバーフローに関して独自に何かを導入することを議論してみてもいいのかも知れません。

参考として、上記 `(**)` でコンセプトの説明のために作られた[ユーザスクリプト](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/963) を紹介しておきます。

Comment: わざわざ翻訳ありがとうござました。
やはり現状はないのですね。　残念です。
私は対してWebデザイン詳しくありませんが、"対応させるとレイアウト崩れるから"というようなことを言われては仕方がない気もします。

Answer (score 5):

2020年12月以降、スタック・オーバーフローにおいても Markdown 記法でテーブル構文がサポートされるようになりました。

詳細については [Markdown のヘルプページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) や、以下のリリース案内も参照してください。

関連メタ:
[Markdown にテーブル構文のサポートが追加されます](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3443)

Answer (score 1):

`<pre> </pre>`を使ってAAでダーティーテーブル？を作ってください

```
 

曜日　１時限　２時限　３時限　４時限　５時限　６時限
 月    数学　　物理　　化学　　体育　家庭科　　音楽
 月    総合　　国語　　数学　　数学　　数学　日本史
 火    体育　　体育　　体育　　体育　　体育　　体育
 水　 世界史　日本史   物理　　化学　　英語
 木    生物　　英語　　化学　　総合　　社会　　体育
 金    数学　　数学　　数学　　数学　　数学　　数学
```

上出力　下実際に書かれているもの

```
<pre> 

曜日　１時限　２時限　３時限　４時限　５時限　６時限
 月    数学　　物理　　化学　　体育　家庭科　　音楽
 月    総合　　国語　　数学　　数学　　数学　日本史
 火    体育　　体育　　体育　　体育　　体育　　体育
 水　 世界史　日本史   物理　　化学　　英語
 木    生物　　英語　　化学　　総合　　社会　　体育
 金    数学　　数学　　数学　　数学　　数学　　数学　

</pre>
```